# connect react and express with HTTPS in the same server(centOS7)

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, https, lets-encrypt

I'm struggling with connecting front end(React app in nginx port 443 https) and BackEnd(express app in the same server port 3000).

I just try to connect them though, it's keeping spit an error: SSL_PROTOCOL_ERR.

here's some code:

1. nginx

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name example.com www.example.com;
 include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
 return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    location / {
     root   /home/app/client/react_app/build; # react
     index  index.html index.htm;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

2. react (post code)

```
export async function postResult() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      url(ex: https://example.com:3000),
      {/*data*/},
      },
      {
        withCredentials: true,
        xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN",
        xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
      }
    );
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

3. express

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const mysql = require("mysql");

const cors = require("cors");

const port = 3000;
app.set("port", 3000);

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  ...
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
const corsOpt = function (req, callback) {
  callback(null, { origin: true });
};

app.options("*", cors(corsOpt));


app.post("/save_result", cors(corsOpt), (req, res) => {
    const params = [];
    ...
    connection.query(sql, params, function (err, rows, fileds) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(rows.insertId);
      }
    });
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
});

https.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server is listening at port->${port}`);
});
```

And now i finally learn https->http is not available, but i don't have any clue to slove this problem.

Can someone please help me 
Thanks!

Comment: your port in the client is incorrect, try- url: https://example.com:3000),

Comment: @Ar26  I wrote code incorrectly just in here, not in my real file But thank you, i edit it!